# Netbook display corrupted

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, display, drive

I use xubuntu 16.04, 
After starting the os the display is 75% corrupted:

[image: example pic]

After that, if I suspend (sleep) the Netbook and then awake it, it shows everything correctly. It happened only on

- xubuntu 17.10
- xubuntu 16.04 (only if I do an upgrade, in original version it doesn't happen)
- xubuntu 14.10 (I think same like 16, without upgrade it works normally)

My netbook is **[Asus Eee_PC_1005HA_Seashell](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/Eee_PC_1005HA_Seashell/specifications/)**.

Comment: it not show me, when i install it, it show when i start os

Comment: See option [3. If an update or something else caused your problem](/a/162078/175814).

Comment: ok i will do it, tnx

Comment: Sorry, but im not see anything, looked like my problem.

Comment: Any issue that describe a blank screen also apply to graphic corruptions in general, since blank screens are simply the most common type of graphics corruption (although they have additional possible causes). I see two of those in section 1. of the aforementioned answer.